# How to get the answers from my survey? (Kotlin App)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, survey

https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/SurveyKit

I want to get the answer, which is within the QuestionResults... The error message from the documentation code just gives me a line for each result, showing a long string with the answer right at the end.

This is what the documentation gives me:

When the survey is finished, you get a callback. No matter of the FinishReason, you always get all results gathered until now.
The TaskResult contains a list of StepResults. The StepResult contains a list of QuestionResults.

```
surveyView.onSurveyFinish = { taskResult: TaskResult, reason: FinishReason ->
    if (reason == FinishReason.Completed) {
        taskResult.results.forEach { stepResult ->
            Log.e("logTag", "answer ${stepResult.results.firstOrNull()}")
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite new to Kotlin so let me off if I'm being stupid here lol. Here is the error messages the above code gives me:

```
E/ASDF: answer IntroQuestionResult(id=StepIdentifier(id=5e2e4b4e-dac2-46ba-a680-28b4c56e8ea6), startDate=Mon May 24 03:22:48 GMT+01:00 2021, endDate=Mon May 24 03:22:48 GMT+01:00 2021, stringIdentifier=)
E/ASDF: answer ScaleQuestionResult(id=StepIdentifier(id=665ac456-7201-4944-970c-a1e5fda931c3), startDate=Mon May 24 03:22:48 GMT+01:00 2021, endDate=Mon May 24 03:22:50 GMT+01:00 2021, stringIdentifier=0.0, answer=0.0)
E/ASDF: answer ScaleQuestionResult(id=StepIdentifier(id=fb062d80-8b59-4259-a294-a785df3bf351), startDate=Mon May 24 03:22:50 GMT+01:00 2021, endDate=Mon May 24 03:22:52 GMT+01:00 2021, stringIdentifier=3.0, answer=3.0)
    answer FinishQuestionResult(id=StepIdentifier(id=2c023f69-756a-4424-bbdf-aeb2868985f4), startDate=Mon May 24 03:22:52 GMT+01:00 2021, endDate=Mon May 24 03:22:53 GMT+01:00 2021, stringIdentifier=)
```

All I want is the answer data (in this case the 0.0 and 3.0) saved as integers to calculate a score.

Comment: Q: Doesn't anybody use Java for Android anymore?

Comment: Not for this lol... Do you know a solution by any chance?